# Order of operations with trig

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'd like to get an opinion on how this expression should be interpreted in order to resolve a disagreement. The expression is originally written as: 
$-\frac{1}{4}cos(2t)^4$

Should this be interpreted as:

(A) $-\frac{1}{4}(cos(2t))^4$ with the cosine evaluated first.

(B) $-\frac{1}{4}cos((2t)^4)$ with the exponent evaluated first.

Comment: Without more context, both interpretations are valid. The probability of the intent $\cos^4(2t)$ is higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is the cosine first, given that the usage of $()$ clearly suggests that the argument to the function is just $2t$.

If that is so, one would probably better write $-\frac14\cos^4(2t)$ to avoid all misunderstandings.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. I agree and thought that it was cosine first, the intent was the later (B) with the exponent evaluated first.

Comment: @user98724 Then you have proof that not parenthesizing expressions can be tragic